# Quadrature rules with the weight function $w(x) = |x|^\gamma$

Tags: quadrature

I am interested in integrals of the form
$$
\int_{[0,1]^{d}} |x|^{\gamma}f(x)dx.
$$

$\gamma>0$ and $f$ has some singular behavior at $\vec{0}$. The weight function $|x|^\gamma$ is commonly used in weighted Sobolev spaces which include reduced regularity functions.

For $d=1$, a Gauss-Jacobi quadrature rule with $(\alpha,\beta) = (0,\gamma)$ can be used to approximate the above integral. For higher dimensions, I don't think this is the case as $|x|^\gamma \neq \prod_{i=1}^{d} x_{i}^{\gamma}$. The choice $(\alpha,\beta)=(0,0)$ (i.e. Gauss-Legendre) does not work well for me since $|x|^{\gamma}f(x)$ still contains a singularity (depending on the value of $\gamma$).

I'm wondering if anyone has literature suggestions for integrals of the above form, even just for 2D would be sufficient. I couldn't find anything in my search even though I thought this would be a weight function someone's looked at before.

Comment: Is the only singularity you're worried about at $|x|=0$? And what do you define as $|x|$ in higher than 1D? the 2-norm? Also I presume that $\gamma > -1$?

Comment: @helloworld922 there can be other singularities but for now, just at x=0. I define $|x|=(\sum_{i=1}^{d} x_{i}^{2})^{1/2}$ and $\gamma > 0$ (generally, $f$ would contain a singularity which is counteracted somewhat by $|x|^\gamma$)

Comment: Assuming the integral converges, there's a good chance regular Gauss-Legendre quadrature might still converge to the correct answer as long as you don't evaluate exactly at a singularity. Have you tried Gauss-Legendre and verified it doesn't work?

Comment: I've seen this weight function before for $\gamma > -1$ and normalized to the interval $[-1,1]$ in the work of Stroud, A. H., and Secrest, D. (1966), _Gaussian quadrature formulas_, Prentice-Hall. The quadrature formulas can be found on pg. 201, and the set of orthogonal polynomials on pg. 88.